# hibernate-orm source import intellij idea 12

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I cloned hibernate-orm project and trying to import it in **Intellij Idea 12** and **Intellij Idea 13**. 
Everything is working, but classes which use **antlr**, like **HqlSqlWalker** doesn't compile because it can't find `org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker` and classes like it.
I tried to run gradle generateSource and build, but it doesn't help.

Thanks

Comment: Try installing the package via maven.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac as I know you can use only gradle to build hibernate

Comment: I solved this problem by regenerating idea project from gradle